# Programming a Honeywell Thermometer -- don't understand why heat is lower than cool?

Tags: thermostat

I'm trying to program a Honeywell thermostat. In the instructions, it states:

[image]

I don't particularly understand why the heat setting has a lower number than the cool setting. My understanding (perhaps flawed), is that the temperature indicated in the graph is what temperature is desired when the heat or cold settings are applied. So I don't really understand why you want a hotter temperature for cold or a colder temperature for hot. Or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: IIRC, US federal law prohibits heating a (public/commercial) building above 68° in the winter and cooling it below 72° in the summer, similar to your settings. It's designed to save money.

Comment: No, it's designed to save the _planet_. We're frogs in kettles.

Comment: @FreeMan In a sense you are both right. The push to conserve energy goes back (in my memory, can't say before then) to the 1970s oil crisis. Then it was "save money" (because energy prices had shot up) and "save oil/gas for where we need it" (because there was a shortage). 50 years later and the same type of rules/regulations/encouragement to change behavior in various ways (set back your thermostat, use carpools/mass transit, insulate buildings better, etc.) are back but this time because of concern about climate change. (Actually, in between there was a similar though lesser phase of

Comment: "do this because otherwise we'll run out of fuel before we have a replacement technology" (variously applied to oil, gas, coal, etc. with replacement variously nuclear, wind, solar, etc.) My *personal* perspective is that if the technology advances such that the better (from a climate/energy/etc. perspective) technology saves money and/or produces a more enjoyable/useful result then it doesn't *matter* what the core reason is - the result is the desired change. As in, Tesla innovated with fun/fast/enjoyable electric cars with a (generally, depends on many factors) significant savings on

Comment: overall energy cost, so while some people buy Teslas (and now other electric cars) because it is "good for the environment" and/or "stop climate change", plenty of others just look at the cars and say "the price, features, overall total cost of ownership, etc." works for me and buy them almost *despite* any climate/etc. issues. Same with new heat pumps - if I'm in the market for a full HVAC replacement and you show me a new system that will save me $ over the course of the lifetime of the system, I don't *care* whether it is good for the rest of the world or not, I'll take it. </rant>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can think of it as the temperature where the associated machine turns on.

So, on the first line, heat will only kick in if the room goes below 70. When that happens, the furnace turns on full blast to get you up to 70.

Likewise, if it's summer, 71 might be a comfortable temperature, so your AC doesn't have to do anything if that's what the room is at. But if the sun heats the room up up, eventually the room will get hot enough the AC will turn on and keep it at max 78.

In that band, neither is on because you're in the comfortable range.

When you are sleeping, that band of comfort widens because you're in bed and not as sensitive.

If you had the two reversed, both would want to turn on and battle each other forever.